# Student - How to await and return postgresql query from a helper function

Tags: node.js, postgresql, async-await, promise, pg

New student here.  I'm trying to learn and understand how to query a postgresql database and await the results.  I wrote a simple test helper function, using node and pg, trying to return the results of a query.  How do I go about and await the results of the query and then return the results?

```
const selectEnvelope = (name) => {
    var envelope = [];
    pool.query('SELECT * FROM envelopes WHERE name = $1', [name])
        .then(results => {
            envelope = results.rows;
        })
    return envelope;
};
```

I think I understand "return envelope" will run before the promise finishes, however I left it there as I think it better shows what I'm trying to accomplish.

I initially tried placing the return inside the .then and get undefined.  Gave it another try with the following code, but only get a promise pending even though it logs correctly.

```
async function selectEnvelope(name) {
    try {
        var envelopes = await pool.query('SELECT * FROM envelopes WHERE name = $1', [name])
        console.log(envelopes);
        return envelopes;
    } catch (err) {
        throw err
    }
};
```

Comment: tl;dr: A value cannot time travel into the past. Any value obtained by an asynchronous call needs to be handled _then_, not now. There is no way to pull a value from _then_ to now. Reorganise your thinking, so that you either propagate the asynchronicity by returning the promise, or you use the value inside your asynchronous function, or you take a callback argument that specifies what will happen to the value once it is received.

Comment: First off, thanks Amadan for your help.  I will continue to study the link you provided.  I added some other methods I tried, but still get stuck with a promise pending.  Trying to understand why it logs correctly before the return

Comment: "*Gave it another try with the following code, but only get a promise pending even though it logs correctly.*" - that's the expected behaviour, and you won't get around that. In the code calling this function, you can just `await` it again